# How to prevent repeated downloading with HuggingFace

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface, stable-diffusion

##### Description:

I am confused on how the installation of the packages are performed. Currently I was working on a StableDiffusion model and every-time I run the code its again and again downloading files which are 3 to 4 Gigs big.

##### Code:

This is the code I was trying to run at first:

```py
from torch import autocast
from diffusers import StableDiffusionPipeline

pipe = StableDiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained(
    "CompVis/stable-diffusion-v1-4", 
    use_auth_token=True
).to("cuda")

prompt = "a photo of an astronaut riding a horse on mars"
with autocast("cuda"):
    image = pipe(prompt)["sample"][0]  
    
image.save("astronaut_rides_horse.png")
```

##### Issue:

When I run the code the following appears in my shell:

```bash
Fetching 16 files:   0%|                                                             | 0/16 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
vae/diffusion_pytorch_model.safetensors:   0%|                                   | 0.00/335M [00:00<?, ?B/s]
unet/diffusion_pytorch_model.safetensors:   0%|                                 | 0.00/3.44G [00:00<?, ?B/s]
safety_checker/model.safetensors:   0%|                                         | 0.00/1.22G [00:00<?, ?B/s]
text_encoder/model.safetensors:   0%|                                            | 0.00/492M [00:00<?, ?B/s]
```

and this happens each and everytime I run the code.

##### What I tried?

I tried installing and cloning the whole git repo. (I honestly don't know why I did that even though I know it wasn't gonna affect a thing!) Also I tried searching for many forums for this issue but not even a single clue, maybe its because of my in-experienced approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are [2 possible solutions](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/14336#issuecomment-964049795):

Saving manually:

```py
from diffusers import StableDiffusionPipeline

model = StableDiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained(
    "CompVis/stable-diffusion-v1-4",
    use_auth_token=True,
)

model.save_pretrained("./my_model_directory/")  # only needed first run
model = StableDiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained("./my_model_directory/")
```

Cache dir:

```py
from diffusers import StableDiffusionPipeline

model = StableDiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained(
    "CompVis/stable-diffusion-v1-4",
    cache_dir="./my_model_directory/",
    use_auth_token=True,
)
```

Comment: So do I have to install unet and vae again and again? Isnt there like a git repo that I can clone once and it doesnt need repeated downloading?

Comment: Nope, once you have downloaded them once, you don't need to download them again. If you which to reuse them, change `./my_model_directory/` to an absolute path.

Comment: For example if I want to use the CompVis/stable-diffusion-v1-4 I would git clone the comvis stable diffusion repo and just give the folders path not a files right?